# Packages "breaks" each other

Tags: apt, package-management

When I try to run `sudo apt-get install` or `sudo apt-get -f install` it gives me the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6 : Breaks: libc6:i386 (!= 2.23-0ubuntu7) but 2.23-0ubuntu6 is installed
 libc6:i386 : Breaks: libc6 (!= 2.23-0ubuntu6) but 2.23-0ubuntu7 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Apt can't resolve this conflict itself you should be able to solve this if you force the installation of the higher of the two package versions:

```
sudo apt-get install -f libc6:i386=2.23-0ubuntu7
```

If Apt still refuses you can resort to a manual installation:

```
cd /tmp
apt-get download libc6:i386=2.23-0ubuntu7
sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.23-0ubuntu7_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```